# Left Ctrl and Fn keys on my HP ProBook 4530s are swapped. How can I restore this

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have HP ProBook 4530s which was working as expected i.e. Ctrl keys and Fn Keys were working correctly. Now somehow these two keys are swapped and I want to restore them so that Ctrl Key work as Ctrl key. Please note that I am running Windows 7 on this machine. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Check the bios settings - it is often an option so that people can configure them like Thinkpads.  Even though it is infuriating on a Thinkpad in the first place.

Comment: I have checked the BIOS settings but I couldn't find anything under system configuration related to function key as suggested on different forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix the issue following the steps mentioned below:

1. Turned off the machine
2. Removed ***both*** A/C power and **Battery** and waited for few seconds
3. Attached battery, and turned on the machine..

and the issue was resolved!